# Deleting directories using single liner command

Tags: linux, shell, unix, rm, rmdir

How to remove more than one directory using single command? Is it possible to do it in one liner? If yes, Please help on this.

```
/osmf/mgmt/scheduler>ls -lrt
total 22
drwx------   2 root     root     12288 Mar 26  2009 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   4 ctmagent controlm  1024 May 24  2010 ctmagent
drwxrwxrwx   3 edwprod  edw       1024 Dec  1 09:53 edi
drwxrwxrwx 120 edwprod  edw       5120 Dec 27 09:37 edw
/osmf/mgmt/scheduler>
```

Can I delete `edi` and `edw` using a single command?

Comment: Is there any characteristics to your directories? Do they all have three letters? Do they all start by e? Do... Do... Do... ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`rm -r edi edw`

`rm` can take an arbitrary number of arguments, and the `-r` flag makes it delete directories recursively. Refer to `man rm` for more details.

Reading manual pages are the best way to get information for your questions.

Answer (score 3):

```
rmdir edi edw
```

if the directories are both empty, otherwise

```
rm -r edi edw
```

or

```
rm -r ed[iw]
```

Comment: Please explain the parameters for future readers/

Answer (score 2):

Specifically for your case:

```
rmdir -r ed[iw]
```

It basically removes any directory with the name of `ed` followed by either `i` or `w`

Answer (score 1):

```
rm -r ed*
```

-r means delete directories. ed* make match edi and edw. if there is another directory name start with ed,please be careful!

Answer (score 0):

`rmdir ed*` if they are empty (shell will expand `ed*` to match `edi` and `edw`, `*` is a wildcard character meaning "any string of characters").

`rm -r ed*` if they are not empty.

**Neither of these commands will move your dirs to the trash bin** so when using them always make sure that you don't need the dirs or their content.