# Is it possible to create more than one directory on a same command?

Tags: linux

I took an examination last week and there was a question asking to create three directories by using one command ; then there was a question asking to delete those directories on a same command. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

Check [here](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/linux-unix/create-make-multiple-directories-at-one-time-using-unix-linux) and [here](http://technosophos.com/2010/04/15/mkdir-creating-multiple-subdirectories-one-command.html)

Removing directories in one command is also possible. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655306/deleting-directories-using-single-liner-command)

Answer (score 2):

You should read `man mkdir` and `man rm`

Comment: I don't have linux on my PC !

Comment: use a search engine, luke! http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?mkdir    http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?rm

Comment: @pheromix you have an exam! linux is free!

Comment: lol , but it is uncorrect to cheat during exam !

Answer (score 2):

```
mkdir -pv myfolder/{a..z}/{1..10}
```

creates 261 folders (myfolder/a/1, myfolder/a/2.... myfolder/z/10)

```
rm -rf myfolder/
```

removes them all